# Python error - "too many indices for array"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a code that works for reading one file and save to a matrix. But I want to read and save several files to a matrix. But when I try to expand my code to work with several file I get following error message "too many indices for array", which I didnt get when only reading one file

I have tried to use a function instead of a for-loop, and also to apply indices differently (as shown in some other threads here on StackOverflow), but it didnt work.

It is this part of the code that dont work properly:

```
r=r[1:lengthOfDataset,1:numberOfColumns]
```

My code in full:

```
dataPath = ['ABB-2018-03-26-2019-03-26.csv',
    'ALFA-2018-03-26-2019-03-26.csv',
    'ALIV-SDB-2018-03-26-2019-03-26.csv',...]


lengthOfDataset=252
numberOfColumns=10
data=np.zeros([len(dataPath),lengthOfDataset-1,numberOfColumns-1])


for i in range(len(dataPath)):
    data[i]=readAndConvertFile(dataPath[i])


def readAndConvertFile(F):
    with open(F, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        lists = list(reader)
        r = np.array(lists)
        r=r[1:lengthOfDataset,1:numberOfColumns]
        for j in range(lengthOfDataset-1):
                for k in range(numberOfColumns-1):
                    r[j,k]=num(r[j,k])
        return r


def num(s):
    try:
        s=s.replace(',','.')
        s=float(s)
        return s
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Comment: What does your csv file look like? What is output of `r.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a numpy array out of a list that only contains one element you'll get an array with a shape of (,1) (only one dimensional) whereas if there are more elements in the list you'll get a shape like (number of files,1) (two-dimensional). I would suggest reshaping the numpy array `r` after it's creation.

```py
np.reshape(r,(-1,1))
```

This makes sure that `r` always has two dimensions, without specifying the number of rows.